# give different styles for contents inside an option tag

Tags: html

i need to align two different contents inside  tag. Means align one text at the left side and other at the right side and need to give two different styles(font,color etc) for both texts is it possible?

Comment: possible.  show your code?

Comment: <option value=<%=userids%>><%=userids %><%=designation%</option>   i need to align this user id in left and designation in right(blur)

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to give style to option tags directly

Comment: no its not possible to stylize Option tag directly, there might JS solution for it this might help you http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/how-to-create-custom-select-menus-with-css.html

Answer (score 0):

**Nope**, you can't have *other HTML tags within the `option` tag*.  So it is not possible with HTML.

```
<select>
    <option><span id="left">left</span><span id="right">right</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

This will be rendered like

```
<select>
    <option>leftright</option> //hence can't be done
</select>
```

But with help of JS, you can create `select` like divs, spans,..  Here you can style it.